# Order of transformations confusion in muPDF Library API documentation

Tags: c, mupdf

From the basics of the C language we know that in the following code:

```
y = fn3(fn2(fn1(x)));
```

...the `fn1()` is executed first, the `fn2()` is executed second and the `fn3()` is executed last.

What order of matrix transformations is built by the following C code ?:

```
ctm = fz_pre_translate(fz_pre_rotate(fz_scale(sx, sy), r), tx, ty);
```

Case A or Case B ?:

[image]

The documentation of the muPDF Library API is available at [this link](https://mupdf.com/docs/mupdf_explored.pdf) and it states the following on Page 61:

> *Alternatively, operations can be specifically applied to existing*
> *matrices. Because of the non-commutative nature of matrix operations,*
> *it matters whether the new operation is applied before or after the*
> *existing matrix. For example, if you have a matrix that performs a*
> *rotation, and you wish to combine that with a translation, you must*
> *decide whether you want the translation to occur before the rotation*
> *(‘pre’) or afterwards (‘post’).*
>
> *MuPDF has various API functions for such operations:*

To me the statement above suggests that the order of transformations, being built by these functions, is not the same as the order of nested function evaluations in C (and their  invocations) ...but I just can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical terms, case **A**, which is a **t**ranslation, *followed* by a **r**otation, *followed* by **s**caling could be expressed as

**x'** = *S* · (*R* · (*T* · **x**)) = *S* · *R* · *T* · **x** = ((*S* · *R*) · *T* ) · **x**

So we want to apply the translation *before* the other transformations combined, while the scaling should only be applied *after*.

*M* = *S* · *R* · *T* = *M<sub>S, R</sub>* · *T* = *S* · *M<sub>R, T</sub>*

> To me the statement above suggests that the order of transformations, being built by these functions, is not the same as the order of nested function evaluations in C.

I'd say that a richer API, like the one exposed by this library, let the user choose between different ways of expressing their intent, but it doesn't (of course) violate the rules of C nested functions calls.

There could be cases in which particular algorithms may benefit from one approach or the other.

```
ctm = fz_pre_translate(fz_pre_rotate(fz_scale(sx, sy), r), tx, ty);
```

Note that, despite the order in which the nested functions are called, this line can be read exactly as the first statement of this answer (first translation, then rotation, then scale), while the mathematical notation is basically backwards.

```
ctm = fz_post_scale(fz_post_rotate(fz_translate(tx, ty), r), sx, sy);
```

Whether this generates confusion or not in the reader, I'm afraid is a matter of opinion and personal backgrounds.

To my knowledge, though, having a small as possible public API is considered less error prone and easier to mantain.

Comment: How can you write 
`x' = S · (R · (T · x)) = S · R · T · x = ((S · R) · T ) · x` when the matrix multiplication is not commutative—the order in which matrices are multiplied is significant.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson [Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Associativity) is a different property.

Comment: You are correct that Associativity is different from Commutativity but I still cannot accept your answer because my experiments with image transformation in MuPDF indicate that the composite transformations are not behaving as you have written.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson Looking at page 59, they show an homogeneous coordinates representation of a point as a *row* vector, multiplied by a transformation matrix. I always followed the [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) of using *column* vectors. This implies that the matrices are transposed and the order is reversed between the two approaches.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson About *"the composite transformations are not behaving as you have written."*, can you please tell if the posted line of code produces the A case or not?